How to have multiple <router-outlet></router-outlet> in the app.component.html
The point is that I want to implement several  in the app.component.html. Depending on whether it is the mobile or desktop view, the order of the components changes. I tried outlet="name" but have duplicate code, which I'm sure can be done better. How can I use router outlet multiple times in a template? I'm using Angular 17. Here is the code:
app.routes.ts
export const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '', component: SummaryViewComponent, outlet: 'router-desktop' },
{ path: 'summary', component: SummaryViewComponent, outlet: 'router-desktop' },
{ path: 'task', component: TaskViewComponent, outlet: 'router-desktop' },
{ path: 'board', component: BoardViewComponent, outlet: 'router-desktop' },
{ path: 'contacts', component: ContactViewComponent, outlet: 'router-desktop' },
{ path: 'privacy-policy', component: ContactViewComponent, outlet: 'router-desktop' 
},
{ path: 'legal-notice', component: ContactViewComponent, outlet: 'router-desktop' },

{ path: '', component: SummaryViewComponent, outlet: 'router-mobile' },
{ path: 'summary', component: SummaryViewComponent, outlet: 'router-mobile' },
{ path: 'task', component: TaskViewComponent, outlet: 'router-mobile' },
{ path: 'board', component: BoardViewComponent, outlet: 'router-mobile' },
{ path: 'contacts', component: ContactViewComponent, outlet: 'router-mobile' },
{ path: 'privacy-policy', component: ContactViewComponent, outlet: 'router-mobile' },
{ path: 'legal-notice', component: ContactViewComponent, outlet: 'router-mobile' },
];

app.component.html
<div class="grid-container-desktop">
    <app-navigation-desktop></app-navigation-desktop>
    <app-header></app-header>
    <div>
        <router-outlet name='router-desktop'></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="grid-container-mobile">
    <app-header></app-header>
    <div>
        <router-outlet name='router-mobile'></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <app-navigation-mobile></app-navigation-mobile>
</div>

app.component.scss
:host {
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}

.grid-container-desktop {
    display: none;
}

.grid-container-mobile {
    display: none;
}

.grid-container-desktop {
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 200px calc(100% - 200px);
    grid-template-rows: var(--header-height) auto;
    grid-template-areas: "navigation-desktop header" "navigation-desktop router-outlet";
}

.grid-container-mobile {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-areas: "header" "router-outlet" "navigation-mobile";
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .grid-container-desktop {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 200px calc(100% - 200px);
        grid-template-rows: var(--header-height) auto;
        grid-template-areas: "navigation-desktop header" "navigation-desktop router-outlet";
    }
    .grid-container-mobile {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .grid-container-mobile {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-rows: var(--header-height) auto auto;
        grid-template-areas: "header" "router-outlet" "navigation-mobile";
    }
    .grid-container-desktop {
        display: none;
    }
}

app-navigation-desktop {
    grid-area: navigation-desktop;
}

app-navigation-mobile {
    grid-area: navigation-mobile;
}

app-header {
    grid-area: header;
}

router-outlet {
    grid-area: router-outlet;
}

.grid-container-desktop>*,
.grid-container-mobile>* {
    border: 5px solid red;
}


This is a terrible idea, because the app will always load and render everything twice, and one of them will just be hidden via CSS. The performance will be horrible, especially on mobile where you can't display as much information anyway.

@Clashsoft How should I then implement the two different layouts?  The order of the components changes depending on whether desktop or mobile view.  What other solution can you think of?

Yes it's not the best idea in most case, but i will be good for very specific use case.
Probably use routerLink="["/", {outlet: {}]"

@software Either you select at the beginning what site you want (mobile/desktop), perhaps with a path prefix (e.g. /dashboard vs /m/dashboard), or you make each component responsive (preferred option, this is much easier to develop as you can easily switch between the display sizes in devtools). You are already on the right track with your media queries.
